# Create star pyramid

Tags: php, web

```
//I want to create a star pyramid..but it not work..can someone assist me to solve it..
```

**This is the code**

```
<?php

for ($x=1;$x<=5;$x++)
{
    echo "<center>";
    for ($y=1;$y=$x;$y++)
    {
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

**This is the output**

---

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\StarPyramid2.php on line 6

Comment: `$y=$x` I wonder when this will be false?

Comment: so how to make solve it..?..give me some idea..

Comment: Well what have you done in your first loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
$stars = "*";
echo "<center>";
for ($x=1;$x<=5;$x++)
{
    echo $stars;
    echo "<br>";
    $stars .= "*";
}
echo "</center>";
```

Comment: If it has answered your question, remember to mark it as the answer for others.